# How do I animate the x1 coordinate of an SVG line with react spring?

Tags: svg, line, react-spring

I'm trying to animate the x1 coordinate of an SVG line with react spring, but nothing is happening. I also don't see any errors or failures logged. How do I animate the position of a line in react-spring?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";

function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const spring = useSpring({
    from: { x1: 5 },
    to: { x1: 22 }
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            setToggle(!toggle);
          }}
        >
          Toggle animation
        </button>
      </div>
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        width="40"
        height="40"
        viewBox="0 0 40 40"
        stroke="#000"
        strokeWidth="2"
      >
        <animated.line
          x1="5"
          y1="10"
          x2="35"
          y2="10"
          transform="rotate(0 23.5 10)"
          styles={spring}
        />
      </svg>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: x1 is not a CSS property, you'd need to use SMIL or javascript to animate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it - it was non-obvious to me, maybe it'll help someone else as well:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";

function App() {
    const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

    const { x1 } = useSpring({
        from: { x1: 5 },
        to: { x1: 22 },
        immediate: toggle === false,
        reset: true
    });

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => {
                        setToggle(!toggle);
                    }}
                >
                    Toggle animation
                </button>
            </div>
            <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                width="40"
                height="40"
                viewBox="0 0 40 40"
                stroke="#000"
                strokeWidth="2"
            >
                <animated.line
                    x1={x1}
                    y1="10"
                    x2="35"
                    y2="10"
                    transform="rotate(0 23.5 10)"
                />
            </svg>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

One can assign the `SpringValue`s created by useSpring directly to the SVG properties and it'll work. Especially useful for those props, which can't be styled as Robert Longson commented on the original post. Thanks for pointing that out.